# maxReceivedMessageSize not read

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, web-config, maxreceivedmessagesize

I am working on a project and I am stuck on a problem, and it is always annoying:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

I have searched very well and found many posts, but most of them were assuming you were hosting the service yourself. In this case I am not so I have absolutely 0 influence on the service configuration.

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="yyyySoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://xxxx:8080/xxx-webservice3/xxxx.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="yyyySoap" contract="xxx.xxxSoap" name="yyyySoap" />
</client>
```

These are my settings that matter (there are way more settings I have serious doubts about if they get read as well). The `maxRecievedMessageSize` is just not working...

I am totally lost, I really have no idea why it still takes the default values.

Just for extra info, the project was originally a windows service but got transformed to be started and run from IIS because it needed to host some webservices as well. So the config that was originally in an app.config was now set into the web.config. The original service now gets started in the `application_start()` in the global.asax.

When we publish the WebProject that references the service project (that calls the webservice) the binaries are built without any configuration files other than the web.config (which I suspect is made by hand, but can't contact the guy who made it....)

Comment: try to add this:
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, if so I would expect another message, not the standard 65536

Comment: try this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx

which actually based on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476853/wcf-error-maximum-number-of-items-that-can-be-serialized-or-deserialized-in-an/8656402#8656402

Answer (score 0):

Omg I feel so damn stupid, it seems the original programmer had the maxReceivedMessageSize hardcoded overridden....