# Why my code is throwing 'the formatter threw an exception'?

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0, app-config, desktop-application

We have an application running on client system for the last 3 years but today it threw exception

[image]

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TokenNumber" value="repodvedsnedmin@9321" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://wpsservices.nsd.pw/card/webservice.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap" contract="wpswebserves.WebServiceSoap" name="WebServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have done everything to make it work but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Error "Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476853/wcf-error-maximum-number-of-items-that-can-be-serialized-or-deserialized-in-an)

Comment: @MaxMokrousov I am using .asmx not WCF

Comment: @Covert - same thing. Take a look at the reader quotas in the linked answer and compare them with yours